# Spring security basic authentication

Tags: java, spring, security

having trouble with spring security here:

I need:

1. `/new-pathx/**`  to be with basic authentication
2. `/health`  permit all.
3. other paths: anyRequest().authenticated()

I have done it this way:

```
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .antMatcher("/new-pathx/**")
      .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
      .csrf().disable()
      .httpBasic().and()
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/health").permitAll()
      .anyRequest()
      .authenticated();
    
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
      .inMemoryAuthentication()
      .withUser(apiUser)
      .password(passwordEncoder.encode(apiPassword))
      .roles("API_USER");
  }
```

Works OK for the `/new-pathx/**` I can only enter with the user and password. But I can get into any other path without any authentication.

Whats wrong with my code?